# How to sending many POST requests with cURL faster

Tags: api, curl, php-curl

I have code to active various gaming platforms for player, the code is working well but it runs very slowly. How can I make it better and run faster?

```
<?php
$_SESSION['username'] = "demo123";
$password = "pass123";
$prefix = "HAN";
$gmusername = $prefix.$_SESSION['username'];
$gmpassword = $password;
$apikey = "SEFOQVBJOjEyMzQ1Njc4";

/////// WM ///////
$params = ['username' => $gmusername];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.gmaster8.com/WM/player/active",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic $apikey"
    ) ,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$gmusername:$gmpassword",
));
curl_exec($curl);

/////// EVOLUTION ///////
$params = ['username' => $gmusername];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.gmaster8.com/EVOLUTION/player/active",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic $apikey"
    ) ,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$gmusername:$gmpassword",
));
curl_exec($curl);

/////// IBC ///////
$params = ['username' => $gmusername];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.gmaster8.com/IBC/player/active",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic $apikey"
    ) ,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$gmusername:$gmpassword",
));
curl_exec($curl);

////// and there are more than 20 other platforms need to be actived like that
?>
```

Is there any solution better to active many platforms? My code above is running without error but it takes too much time loading for player when registering and activing permision to access among gaming platforms.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to refactor your curl calls down to a single instance and pass the uri as a variable. such as using $base_url = 'https://api.gmaster8.com/'; $uri = 'EVOLUTION/player/active';CURLOPT_URL =>$base_url.$uri, . Having one set of curl calls to optimize will go much smoother than 20 separate ones. As for making it go faster we would need objective timings and goals to really dig into that. There may be some curl headers that could help. Personally have switched to guzzle for HTTP requests.

Comment: Can you raise me an basic demo for the method as you said. Very thank you.